# Excel Header and Footer text replacement is too slow, are there alternatives?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to replace a specific set of words in excel left header (and every header and footer for this matter) with VBA
The problem is it's too slow, taking around 40 seconds for 2 sheets..

I've done it with the substitute command:

```
With osheet.PageSetup
    For i = 1 To footerfindreplace.count
          .LeftHeader = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.LeftHeader, footerfindreplace(i).TextReplace, footerfindreplace(i).TextReplaceBy)
    next i
End with
```

There's also this alternative, but replaces all the text into the word I want, and doesn't keep the remaining text I don't want to replace.

```
If .LeftHeader = footerfindreplace(i).TextReplace Then
     .LeftHeader = footerfindreplace(i).TextReplaceBy
End If
```

Update,

Upon suggestion also tried VBA.replace
It takes exactly the same time.. 20 seconds to open the file with the text replaced, regardless of the command to do it. I also tried putting the loop in different places, still no improvements.
Is it normal to take 20 seconds to replace all headers and footers in 20 seconds?

Im looking at around 15 text find and replace possibilities, but for the same number of possibilities cells.replace command works perfectly without delays.

Thanks for any help

Comment: As there is no issues with your code and your query is regarding enhancements / improvements to your code, it might be worth asking this question on SuperUser

Comment: I'm not sure this is just an enhancement, it's too slow of a replace to be as such. I'm talking about only 2 sheets, and I do believe the code should be faster on this. On cells, which are way more, I'm also doing a replace with osheet.Cells.replace and is much faster

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using VBA.Replace?
This Code replaces all "Foo" in the LeftHeader with "Bar".

Replace `Set pgSetup = Sheet1.PageSetup` with whatever you need and loop if necessary.

```
Sub testRep()
    Dim pgSetup As PageSetup
    Dim findStr As String
    Dim repStr As String

    Set pgSetup = Sheet1.PageSetup
    findStr = "Foo"
    repStr = "Bar"

    pgSetup.LeftHeader = VBA.Replace(pgSetup.LeftHeader, findStr, repStr)

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Added some additional Code, with this you should see how long an update takes.
For comparison, with the code below (testRep2), updating 5 sheets with 3 Headers (R,C,L) each it takes between 0.1 and 1 seconds per sheet (ca. 3x faster than without the `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.DisplayStatusBar`).

```
Sub testRep2()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim findStr As String
    Dim repStr As String
    Dim start As Long
    Dim startSheet As Long

    findStr = "Foo"
    repStr = "Bar"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    start = timer
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        startSheet = timer
        With sht.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = VBA.Replace(.LeftHeader, findStr, repStr)
            .CenterHeader = VBA.Replace(.CenterHeader, findStr, repStr)
            .RightHeader = VBA.Replace(.RightHeader, findStr, repStr)
        End With
        Debug.Print sht.Name, timer - startSheet
    Next sht
    Debug.Print "Total:", timer - start

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sheet1 (5)     0.796875 
Sheet1 (4)     0.34765625 
Sheet1 (3)     0.89453125 
Sheet1 (2)     0.42578125 
Sheet1         0.96875 
Total:         2.96875
```

Comment: It does the same as the second option I posted, for some reason, it erases all the text, and puts only the "Bar". For example, if I have "Foo 123", it will become "Bar", when I wanted "Bar 123" in that case.. I wonder why

Comment: Interesting, I tested it and it worked. But I know that there are some Issues with Headers/Footers in Excel, newer Versions also seem to have a lower character limit. Do the headers/footers you try to edit contain "Fields"? Replace would probably not be able to identify the value placed inside the header by them.

Comment: Ok, VBA.replace is now replacing only the selected text, but still too slow. It only happens on the line of the replacement, the loop works flawlessly.. I wonder why

Comment: Have you tried the usual suspects of Application.ScreenUpdate etc?

Comment: Looking around the web with search terms like: VBA, pagesetup, slow, there seem to be quite a few topics around. Remember that even 15 year old forum/blog posts can still be relevant for VBA today.